# Where should I initialize the array in a for-each loop?

Tags: java, loops, foreach

Would the following create unnecessary memory usage

```
    String[] words = text.split(" ");
    for (String s : words)
    {...}
```

Or would the following call `text.split(" ")` every time the loop is repeated

```
    for (String s : text.split(" "))
    {...}
```

Which way would be more preferable?

Comment: This sounds like coding convention question and the answer is quite subjective. Personally, I prefer the first way.

Comment: Both solutions use a similar amount of memory.

Answer (score 6):

There are pluses to each way of writing your loop:

- The first way is more debuggable: you can set a breakpoint on the `for`, and inspect `words`
- The second way avoids introducing a name `words` into the namespace, so you can use the name elsewhere.

As far as performance and readability go, both ways are equally good: the `split` will be called once before the start of the loop, so there are no performance or memory usage consequences to using the second code snippet.

Comment: There is no difference in memory usage either

Answer (score 1):

Since, there is no difference in terms of performance I think:

```
String[] words = text.split(" ");
for (String s : words)
{...}
```

should be used because you can still use the words generated by `text.split(" ")` for further data manipulation. In the second approach, you can only the words inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code getList() is only called once.
So I think there is no differences performance-wise about the 2 ways you asked.

```
class Test {

    static int[] list = {1,2,3,4,5};

    static int[] getList() {
        System.out.println("getList executed");
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int n: getList()) {
            System.out.println("n = "+n);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
getList executed
n = 1
n = 2
n = 3
n = 4
n = 5
```